# Leibniz rule for cumulative normal distribution

Tags: calculus, statistics, partial-derivative

I am trying to take the derivative of the multivariate cumulative normal distribution wrt a certain parameter x. Both the mean (**H**x, where **H** is a n x 1 vector) and the variance (n x n matrix **T**) of my normal distribution depend on x.

$$\frac{\int_{t=-\infty}^{t=\mathbf{H}x} \vert \mathbf{T}_i \vert^{-1/2}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} e^{-.5t'\mathbf{T}^{-1}_it}dt}{\partial x}$$

However, when I want to apply the Leibniz rule, I first take the derivative of the upper bound (a vector wrt a scalar) and I end up with a n x 1 vector. Next, I take the derivative of my normal distribution, and I end up with a n x n matrix. What is my mistake?

Comment: For clarity: $x$ is $1\times 1$ (scalar) and is multiplied element-by-element to each element of $\mathbf{H}$? Also by $t=-\infty$ you mean the integration $\int_{-\infty}(...)\int_{-\infty}$?

Comment: H is indeed a vector that is multiplied element by element with scalar x, and $t=-\infty$ indicated that the lower bound of the integrals is minus infinity